# Is it necessary to link to all landing pages from the homepage?

Tags: seo, sitemap, links, landing-page, site-structure

What I am wanting to do is build quite a few landing pages targeting specific keywords from google search.  These pages will give a brief explanation of what we do and how we can help them with what they are looking for.  Along with that, they will have a signup form.

My question is where should these go in the site structure?  Should the homepage link to all of them somehow?  Or should the homepage link to some 'features' page or 'sitemap' page that then links to all of the landing pages?  Or maybe the pages don't need to be linked from the homepage at all and can just be included in the sitemap.  I feel that the last option probably isn't the best idea.

EDIT: Quite a few is around 50 - 100.  I plan on getting uses to the page by targeting niche ketwords and probably some adwords traffic as well.  However I don't know if they need to be linked to somewhere in my site.

Comment: How do you want the visitors to find your landing pages? Via what channel?

Comment: How many is "quite a few".

Comment: I went ahead and updated my question.

Comment: If they will be for driving paid search traffic from the likes of AdWords then don't link them on your site anywhere. Just build the landing pages with minimal distractions purely for the purpose of converting the visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal links does matter.

read https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/138752?hl=en

> The **number** of internal links pointing to a page **is a signal to search
>   engines** about the relative importance of that page. If an important
>   page does not appear in this list, or if a less important page has a
>   relatively large number of internal links, you should consider
>   reviewing your internal link structure.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to link pages of your website with each other. But it's not necessary to reference to all pages from the home page.

Besides of that, if you have some pages that are not linked from other pages, then you should include them in the XML sitemap, otherwise search engines won't find them at all.

Comment: Although the OP is specifically asking about "landing" pages. You seem to be answering with respect to "all pages" - or does the same methodology apply in your opinion?

Comment: IMO, the methodology is correct for all pages, **especially** for landing pages.

Comment: If I just put the pages in my sitemap would that hurt their rank if they weren't linked to somewhere else in my site.  Linking to them seems a little unnecessary and would be a little awkward unless they were just linked to from an archives page or something.

Comment: No one knows for sure that putting the links in the sitemap only will affect your SERP. But I'd linked them anyway, at least from "category", or "archive" page, or smth like this.

Answer (score 1):

When I hear the term *landing pages* I get worried. Often, these are too closely related content wise. If however, they are unique content pages, then I would breath a bit better. Here is why. Google has gotten smarter about landing pages recently. It is possible, that some pages will be too closely related even if they are tuned for specific keywords. If these pages are not linked, or the links are buried, then Google may discount these pages entirely. If they are too closely related, then they could be seen as spam. Landing pages as a concept is a fine line to walk. The old adage is new again. Create content for humans and not machines. If you are creating landing pages, make them stand as valuable content each on their own and not as semi-copies of the same thing. Then make sure you link them like any other content. It is possible to make effective landing pages if you remember that Google begrudgingly accepts them but would rather not. Make landing pages that Google would say *ok* to.

Best of luck!